If $Y \subset X$ is a hypersurface so that $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$ is positive, then $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(Y)$ is an isomorphism.
This is coming from exercise 5.2.10 in Huybrechts' book on complex geometry. The exact statement of the exercise is as follows.

Let $Y$ be a hypersurface of a compact complex manifold $X$ with $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$ positive. Suppose that $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^2(Y, \mathbb{Z})$ are torsion free. Prove that restriction induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(Y)$ if $\dim X \geq 4$. (Use the exponential sequence and the weak Lefschetz theorem. The assumption on $H^2(\;\;\;, \mathbb{Z})$ is superfluous, see the comments at the end of this section.)

In this book, the "weak Lefschetz theorem" mentioned above is the statement that in the above setting, the restriction map $H^i(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^i(Y, \mathbb{C})$ is an isomorphism for $i < \dim X - 1$ and injective for $i = \dim X - 1$. The relevant comment at the end states the following.

The weak Lefschetz theorem actually holds for the integral cohomology groups.

Given the Lefschetz theorem for integral cohomology groups, this exercise is fairly easy using the exponential sequence and the five lemma. However, the comments after the exercise, and the torsion-free assumption on $H^2$, make it seem like there is another way Huybrechts intended us to solve this problem.
What is this intended solution? I'll record how far I got below.
If we look at the relevant part of the long exact sequence associted to the exponential sequence we get the following diagram.$\require{AMScd}$ $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
\begin{CD}
H^1(X, \Z) @>>> H^1(X, \O_X) @>>> \operatorname{Pic}(X) @>>> H^2(X, \Z) @>>> H^2(X, \O_X)\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV  \\
H^1(Y, \Z) @>>> H^1(Y, \O_Y) @>>> \operatorname{Pic}(Y) @>>> H^2(Y, \Z) @>>> H^2(Y, \O_Y)
\end{CD}
By the weak Lefschetz theorem for $\mathbb{C}$-coefficients and the Hodge decomposition, the second and fifth vertical maps are isomorphisms. Similarly, since $H^i(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^i(X, \mathbb{Z})$ (for $i = 1,2$) are an isomorphisms upon tensoring by $\mathbb{C}$, these maps are additionally injective by the torsion-free assumption. To apply the five lemma we need them to both be surjective as well.
I'm having a very hard time showing this surjectivity. The closest way to do this I could think of is to compare the cohomology groups $H^j(X, Y; \mathbb{Z})$ and $H^{k}(X\setminus Y; \mathbb{Z})$ using some kind of Lefschetz duality, but showing that $H^{k}(X\setminus Y; \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes in high degree is the theorem of Andreotti and Frankel, which is quite nontrivial, especially since we have to use Kodaira's embedding theorem and some algebraic geometry to justify that $X \setminus Y$ is in fact a smooth complex affine variety. As such, this is probably not the right path.
Thanks!
